# How do I pass information back to my application as part of the facebook login process?

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm looking at .Net code which performs a facebook login, using the C#/.Net library wrappers.

I would like to pass an identifier into the log-in attempt, with the goal of having facebook pass it back to me once the user has been authenticated.

I'm constructing the redirect url for the request manually, and I've tried both of the following without much success:

```
oAuthClient.RedirectUri = 
  new Uri( "http://localhost:3434/fbOAuth?token=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode( token ) ); 
  //fails when attempting to get access token - 
  //"oAuthClient.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken( code )" throws an exception.

var loginUri = oAuthClient.GetLoginUrl( new Dictionary<string, object>
        { { "state", returnUrl }, {"app_data", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token)} } ); 
//doesn't pass app_data back to my application
```

How do you pass arguments to your application as part of the facebook login process?

Comment: This isn't how OAuth 2.0 works.  All you are suppose to get back is a token, and the state ( i.e. sucess failure ) of the user giving you permission, to their Facebook account.

Comment: @Ramhound I hear you. How is this kind of functionality typically provided with OAuth 2.0 systems, then?

Comment: My experience is that Facebook doesn't redirect you to "localhost" for security reasons, you need to add an entry in your host file, e.g.: local.mywebsite.com to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Ramhound may not be aware that as part of the Facebook server-side OAuth design there is explicit support for passing an app-specific parameter named 'state' which you do get back.  The intended use is to protect against CSRF.  see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the Facebook C# SDK for building Facebook apps too.  What I don't use is their authentication stuff.  In my experience, authentication is the hardest part of the overall Facebook app implementation.  Getting it right for all devices and all browsers is hard.

You can use the `state` parameter to pass data of your choosing to Facebook as part of the server-side OAuth design.  The Facebook C# SDK chose to use the `state` parameter to provide context of where to redirect the user on the completion of authentication.  That is not how Facebook intended `state` to be used.  From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ :

> Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)
>
> Cross site request forgery is an attack in which a trusted (authenticated and authorized) user unknowingly performs an action on website. To prevent this attack, you should pass an identifier in the state parameter, and then validate the state parameter matches on the response. We strongly recommend that any app implementing Facebook user login implement CSRF protection using this mechanism.

In my own server-side Facebook OAuth implementation, I generate a GUID, concatenate some state info such as the controller to return to, encrypt that string, and pass it as the state parameter.

When it comes back I decrypt it and away I go.  You could do something like that to pass whatever stateful app-specific data you want.

The server-side OAuth design is pretty straightforward and well documented at the page linked above.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code in an `ActionResult`. Please note my comment on your question not to use "localhost" in the redirect uri:

```
string returnUrl = "http://productionserver.com/account/fblogon";
#if DEBUG
  returnUrl = "http://local.developmentserver.com:12345/account/fblogon"; // add this host in hostfile to 127.0.0.1
#endif
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "response_type", "code" }, { "display", "page" } };
parameters["redirect_uri"] = returnUrl;
var url = oauth.GetLoginUrl(parameters).OriginalString;
return Redirect(url);
```